# Mathjax module does not render on edit ckeditor

Tags: wysiwyg

I have installed mathjax module and ckeditor module, but when I try to insert math code using math button on ckeditor, the math codes does not rendered correctely, math code become hidden. Math code rendered successly after content is submited.

is there anyone can help me to fix?

### here my screenshot

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using D7, it seems like the solution is in this [MathJax issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/mathjax/issues/2215409).  Requires some patching / adding plug-ins to ckeditor.

Comment: I have tried to follow the step on that issue but no success. Could you give me some clues which one that i have to patch or add plug-ins?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the mathjax CDN url from the config/content authoring/mathjax, and paste it in CKEditor-full html-advanced options-custom Javascript configuration, then it works! Note the pasted format should be “config.mathJaxLib=url”.